# How to increment decimal value?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In the table `user` has a column `points`.

I want to increment decimal values on it.

```
@user = User.find(@ok.user_id)
@user.points = @user.points + 0.8
@user.save
```

If instead of `+ 0.8` I put `+ 1` works.

I'm using Mysql and the column is a DECIMAL.

Comment: Why is the column for points a varchar rather than a decimal? Would make much more sense if you use it as a decimal, if it was a decimal!

Comment: Ok. I've changed to decimal but doesn't work yet

Comment: Could you give more details than `it doesn't work`? What do you get with `@user.points.class`?

Comment: Please never do things like `m.p = m.p + n; m.save` for incrementing a column value, do it inside the database to avoid race conditions and lost data.

Comment: @muistooshort How I do this?

Comment: @BroiSatse for the terminal, aparently this doesn't save... but don't give me any errors

Comment: I'd probably add a method which does a direct `update t set points = points + 0.8 where ...` SQL call to the database.

Comment: Using `irb` or some other debugger, what is the class of the points (`@user.points.class`). I fear that you may have changed the migration file, but failed to run `rake db:migrate`. Test by checking the class of the method. It should be a decimal (BigDecimal) type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increment in an efficient, reliable way:

```
User.where(id: @ok.user_id).update_all([ 'points=points+?', 0.8 ])
```

That avoids race conditions and doesn't require loading the model. The down-side here is any models you do have loaded are out of date and will need to be updated with `reload` before they're used as their points count is off, but that's not a bad thing. Any number of modifications might have gone on in the background.